# Just updated Ubuntu to 11.04 and my wired internet is down! Help?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

Okay, I just updated Ubuntu to 11.04 and my wired internet connection is down.  The old setup used a static IP, but I'm not even interested in maintaining that.  I just want wired internet access.  Here's the extent of my troubles as cataloged thus far:

- No Wired Internet (wireless works fine)
- No Networking icon w/out running nm-applet from terminal (it goes away again when I close the terminal
- When I DO run nm-applet and click on the networking icon at the top of the screen "wired network" is greyed out, and right below that it says "device not managed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.  I edited /etc/network/interfaces which looked like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.115
     network 192.168.1.2
     netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I'm not sure how it should have been correctly setup for dhcp, but what I have now seems to work fine, so I'll stick w/ that.

Comment: select your answer as the accepted one.I was going to advise you to do the same! :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your terminal and use

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

to configure your wired internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
and changed managed=false to true and then do sudo service network-manager restart

Answer (score -2):

make sure your account is an Administrator.  By default the account you create when installing the OS is given "custom" permissions, which does not grant you the ability to change the system's settings.  You do not have to log in as root to elevate your permissions.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the account you create when installing can't change the system's settings. The account created when installing Ubuntu most certainly is (and always has been) an administrator account. The group memberships may be "custom" but this user is a member of the `admin` and/or `sudo` groups (depending on which Ubuntu release you're using), and that's what matters. Furthermore, a non-administrator cannot make  him/herself an administrator; it would be necessary to use single user mode (such as recovery mode) or a live CD to fix this.